# illegal bulk import with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I'm trying to bulk import JSON file into my ES index using cURL.
I run

```
curl -u username -k -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'https://elasticsearch.website.me/search_data/company_services/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @services.json
```

and it returns

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The structure of my json is

```
{ "services": [
{ "id":1}, 
{"id":2},
...]
}
```

Not sure why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer read of the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) documentation for what the contents of your data file should be. It's worth noting that in your data file *each line* should be a JSON object. The file shouldn't be a typical `.json` file structure, which is what you have at present.

Your file might look something like the following:

```
{"index": {"_id":"1"}}
{"field1":"foo1", "field2":"bar1",...}
{"index": {"_id": "2"}}
{"field1":"foo2", "field2":"bar2",...}
```